# MYSQL Join Confusion

Tags: mysql, sql, join, aggregate-functions

I have this Exams table and Responses table. I want to fetch all records where Exam for exam = 000663

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM Responses r  
  JOIN Exams E ON r.category_id_fk = E.id 
              AND r.exam_id_fk = 000663
```

There are actually total 106 rows only containing responses for exams 000663. But it returns all response rows which are for all exams! Shouldn't it consider r.exam_id_fk = 000663?

I did not use where clause cause I have 3 other tables joining to this query.

Comment: You must use where clause, there's no problem with it, even with other joins

Comment: What is the data type of the `RESPONSES.exam_id_fk` column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 000663 condition belongs in a `WHERE` clause, rather than in the `JOIN` relationship conditions.  Even if you have other tables joining against this (as a subquery), you can still use a `WHERE` clause.

```
select count(*)
from  Responses r  
join Exams E on r.category_id_fk = E.id 
WHERE r.exam_id_fk=000663;
```

Comment: -1: When using an INNER JOIN, there's no difference between using the WHERE vs JOIN's ON clause.  That's not the case for OUTER JOINs...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming E.id is the exame id and r.exam_id_fk is also the exam id try

```
select count(*)
from Exams e
left join Responses r on r.exam_id_fk = e.id
where e.id = 000663;
```

It appears you are joining on the exam id equaling a category id and your condition should be in the where clause

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are using incorrect column name. Use `AND e.id = 000663` instead of `AND r.exam_id_fk = 000663`, so your query would work without a `WHERE`.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Responses r  
JOIN Exams E ON r.category_id_fk = E.id 
AND e.id = 000663
```